# Proof related to squared Euclidean and absolute value metrics

Tags: inequality

If $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$, then $|x+y|\leq 1$?
It's probably very easy, but I can't solve it : )

It's a part of bigger problem.

I have to do this one: I know that $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$.  I must find a smallest number n which fulfills $|x+y|+|x-y|\leq n$. It's probably $2$, but I don't know how to show that.

I know that $|x| \leq 1$, $|y| \leq 1$. It's easy to show that $|x+y|+|x-y| \leq  |x|+|y|+|x|+|y| \leq 4$.
But how to get $2$.

Comment: Have you made any attempts on the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sharpest bound would be $|x+y|\leq \sqrt{2}$, 1 is not possible.

Comment: Please use an *informative* title to your question, to help others find it later.

Comment: "I must find a smallest number n which fulfills |x+y|+|x-y|≤n"  Try squaring both sides.

Answer (score 5):

Take $\;x=y=\cfrac1{\sqrt2}\;$ and get a straighforward counterexample ...

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong. For example, if $x=y=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$, then $x^2+y^2=1$ but $|x+y|=\sqrt2>1$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Restrict your attention to $x,y \geq  0$ for a moment.

The first inequality says that $y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$ which is a quarter circle with radius $1$. The second is the area in between the line $y=1-x$ and the two axes.

Does being in a quarter circle imply being below the line?

Comment: This approach also makes it clear how one should weaken the second inequality to make it always valid.

Answer (score 2):

See graphics  for $x^2+y^2=1$ and $\vert   x + y \vert=1 $

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, take $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, then $x^2+y^2=1$ but $x+y =\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2} > \frac{1+1}{2} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, try to characterise the set of solutions $(x,y)$ in the plane..

Answer (score 1):

we are trying to find $|x+y|+|x-y|\le n$. So by the triangle inequality, 
$$ |2x|=|x+y+x-y|\le |x+y|+|x-y|\le n$$ 
Since $x^2+y^2\le 1$ $x$ we have
$$|x|\le x^2\le x^2+y^2\le 1$$
This implies that 
$$2|x|=|2x|\le 1+1=2$$
Therefore $n=2$

Comment: @Joe The rest of what you were trying to do is superfluous and false as the earlier answers can easily show.

Comment: for $ x=\sqrt{2}/2 $  and $ y=\sqrt{2}/2 $  we have  $|x+y|+|x-y|\le \sqrt{2}$, but if the inequality must be fulfilled for all points of the unit circle then really $n=2$ is the solution..

Comment: If we were trying to find the smallest n for which the inequality $|x+y|+|x-y|\le n$ holds then the smallest $n$ would be 0, since $x=y=0$ is a solution for $x^2+y^2\le 1$. I assumed he meant:  Find the smallest $n$ such that $|x+y|+|x-y|\le n$ $\forall x,y\in \mathbb R$ where $x^2+y^2\le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$|x+y| + |x-y| \le n$

Square both sides:

$(x+y)^2 + (x-y)^2 + 2|(x+y)(x-y)| \le n^2\\
2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2|x^2-y^2| \le n^2$

$|x^2-y^2| = (x^2 + y^2) \cos (2\arctan \frac yx) < (x^2 + y^2)\\
x^2 + y^2 \le 1\\
(|x+y| + |x-y|)^2 \le 4 (x^2 + y^2) \le 4 \le n^2\\
n \ge 2$